# Maintainance of a (Gitlab) Wiki (Broken Links, Page Rename, etc.)

Tags: gitlab, wiki

I'm trying to create a documentation Wiki for our internal software on Gitlab.
The starting point was a messy set of texts, partly from some LaTeX script but also other sources.

My biggest issue at this point is to ensure the correctness of all cross-references/links within the wiki.

I'm steadily cleaning up page by page, but it seems impossible to fix all the broken links. Especially, if some pages are renamed, or moved to another folder, every reference to this page is broken. It is also annoying to verify each link manually, i.e. by clicking on it just to see whether it links to some destination or not.

So, my question is: Are there any tools for checking the integrity of a Gitlab wiki?

I'm thinking of something like this: If I clone the entire Wiki into my machine (via git), I have a folder structure, populated with markdown files. Some tools should run recursively through all these files/folders and at least give me a list of broken links.

Of course, some re-factoring tools that would update links in other pages if I move/rename a page would be even more awesome.

Comment: The trouble is that wikis are crude and fragile, as you've discovered. Links are indeed tied to titles and are not updated. There is no hierarchy. What you're doing is a misuse of wiki. Switch to e.g Jekyll and GitHubPages.

Comment: Some Wiki engines' implementations are crude and fragile. Some are not. A well implemented Wiki engine would maintain link integrity. Sadly many do not or do not do this well.

Comment: @matt you did read the part where this was about gitlab, not github, right? They're two _completely_ different products. If this user is using a self-hosted gitlab instance, telling them to switch to a completely different product with completely different features that can't even be installed as standalone is kind of disingenuous.

Answer (score 1):

Consider whether [markdown-link-check](https://github.com/tcort/markdown-link-check) might work for you. [FOSDEM has a good introductory article](https://fosdem.org/2021/schedule/event/ttdlinkcheck/).

I was not able to use [markdown-link-check](https://github.com/tcort/markdown-link-check) for an Azure DevOps Wiki (cloned git repo.), presumably due to the need for an implicit '.md' added to the links. Although, I did not put much effort into the attempt.

I could - and may eventually - fork the source and adapt it to Azure DevOps Wiki. You might find that it works out-of-the-box for GitLab's Wiki or, you may be able to adapt it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am exploring a seemingly more promising alternative.  The [unified collective](https://unifiedjs.com/learn/guide/introduction-to-unified/) ([Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn)) and its [remark markdown processor](https://remark.js.org/) - and third-party plugins. Being new to the [Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn) paradigm, it's "_tough sledding_" but, I think it will be a more useful solution.